# how to hidden parent element innertext if span tag is exits some value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make `display:none` parent element innertext If span element has some value and the same if span tag has empty value, i want to make it `display: block`.

Hope it would be clear.

```js
var $value = $('div').children().remove().end().text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  test
  <span>span element</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot hide the parent element without also hiding its children. What is the exact output you want to achieve?

Comment: I would wrap the text you want to hide in a separate span and hide that

Comment: You need to provide more information and context; as it is the question is of the format "I want do do the impossible!" but you haven't explained why, which is (currently) all we're going to focus on.

Comment: i want to show parent div inner text only if span tag is exits some value

Comment: Then you need to [edit] that into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to <strike>remove</strike> hide all child text nodes and not elements... Here you go...

```js
$(function() {
  $("div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("span").text()) {
      $(this)
      .contents()
      .filter((i, node) => node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
      .wrapAll("<span style='display:none'></span>");
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  test
  <span>span element</span>
</div>
<div>
  test 2
  <span>span element 2</span>
</div>
<div>
  test 3
</div>
<div>
  test 4
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly, correct, but i don't want to hidden by jquery and the same way can able to achieve in css like `display:none` and `display: block`

Comment: Okay I'll fix that

Comment: @jinfy Fixed it

Comment: @jinfy You're welcome! Also, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you can do something like that -

```
// keep the children elements
var children = $('#div-id').children();
// remove div content
$('#div-id').html('');
// return the children
$('#div-id').append(children);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just replacing with the text you want?

```js
var $value = $('span').text();
if($value != null) $('div').text($value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  test
  <span>span element</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out

```
if($('div').children().text()!= ''){
     $('div').children().text($('div').children());
}
```